# Copy multiple HTML5 layered canvases to one image in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, clipboard

I have multiple HTML5 canvases which are placed on top of one another. The order is important. Canvas 2 will be placed on Canvas 1 and so forth.

a) Is there a way I can create a single image (using toDataURL()) of all of these canvases keeping the same order?

b) And, then how can I copy this image to a clipboard so that it can be pasted in other applications?

Comment: For *a)* You can get the data from each canvas and apply to some master canvas in your order, if that's what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Steps:

1. Create a new Canvas (maybe hidden)
2. Copy both canvas to the new canvas
3. Copy to image using `canvas.toDataURL()`

See this fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/137f623c/

Let's say you have 3 canvas (2 source and 1 combined - hide this if you want) and an image:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas1" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
<canvas id="myCanvas2" width="400" height="200"></canvas>

<canvas id="combined" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
<img src="" id="image" />
```

And, the Script:

```
var canvas1 = document.getElementById("myCanvas1");
var ctx1 = canvas1.getContext("2d");
ctx1.fillStyle = "red";
ctx1.fillRect(10,10,100,100);

var canvas2 = document.getElementById("myCanvas2");
var ctx2 = canvas2.getContext("2d");
ctx2.fillStyle = "blue";
ctx2.fillRect(50,50,300,100);

var combined = document.getElementById("combined");
var ctx = combined.getContext("2d");

ctx.drawImage(canvas1, 0, 0); //Copying Canvas1
ctx.drawImage(canvas2, 0, 0); //Copying Canvas2

document.getElementById("image").src = combined.toDataURL()
```

**Don't forget consider MarkE's Answer (for part b) and also see for compatibility among browsers. As far for copying I see that most modern browsers have `Copy Image` when right clicked. For old browsers, :\ uploading to server and downloading might be the solution.**

Comment: Does it matter if the canvases are of different width and height?

Comment: @kkonweb, I would recommend to use the equal sizes canvas. However, if your canvas size are greater than the final canvas, the part will be cropped. Else, no problem

Comment: Thank your for the code snippet. It appears that I should be all set as far as part (a) of the problem is concerned.

Comment: Oh yes, @kkonweb. I meant part (b) solution is already posted by markE. I meant to see that solution.

Answer (score 1):

**As to part b) of your question...**

You will have problems copying the merged canvas content to the clipboard because the required `Clipboard API` is not yet uniformly or well supported by modern browsers:

http://caniuse.com/#feat=clipboard

**A workaround would be to:**

1. Upload the canvas.toDataURL to your server and save it as an image file,
2. Download that image from the server and add it as an img element.

Then users can `right-click-copy` the img to their clipboard.

Comment: I have suppressed the browser's default right-click context menu. So, I will be adding a new item in my context menu saying "Copy". Also, instead of going to the server to get the image, I was thinking of the following:

a) When an user selects the "Copy" option, I will hide the canvas element and create a IMG element in the DOM with SRC set to the value returned by toDataUrl().

b) Now, can I somehow copy the IMG element with SRC attribute value to the clipboard to achieve successful pasting?

Comment: Sure. You can omit the bounce-off-server step and replace it by directly adding an img element to the page (or to another browser tab). At that point, the context menu on the new img must be the system context menu if you want the user to save to their local drive or to the clipboard. The important point is that the user must confirm the save / clipboardCopy through the system or else that save / clipboard copy will be disallowed. ;-)

Comment: The challenge is that we suppress CEF's context menu completely. So, even if I create a IMG element, I might have to write my own copy image to clipboard functionality! Let me know if there is any other way of doing it.

Comment: *There is no solution which does not require user confirmation through the system.* Valid security concerns require that all local-file-save or copy-to-clipboard operations be confirmed by the user.