# How to save multiple canvas element into a single image (javascript)

Tags: javascript, canvas

How can I combine (append, if it makes sense, not composite) canvas elements into a single image? Idea is to have something like a flag in vertical position.

Currently I have:

```js
var cHeader = document.getElementById("headerImg");
var ctx = cHeader.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 150, 100);

var cBody = document.getElementById("bodyImg");
var ctx = cBody.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 150, 100);

var cFooter = document.getElementById("footerImg");
var ctx = cFooter.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFF00";
ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 150, 100);
```

```html
<canvas id="headerImg"></canvas><br />
<canvas id="bodyImg"></canvas><br />
<canvas id="footerImg"></canvas><br />
```

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using 3 separate canvases?

Comment: hi Cerbrus, each div receives / generates images from different functions. When I tried to make them in a single div, images were overlaping, I would rather have them append - visually similar to the div example I posted .

Comment: How do you come by these images? Are you loading complete images / base64 data, or are you drawing lines on the canvases?

If you're loading the data, you could also load it into image tags, instead of using the canvases. If you're drawing the lines, you could do that in a hidden canvas, and then copy the result to an img tag...

Comment: Second option sounds like a possible solution, will look for some documentation on it. Thanks

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30265024/copy-multiple-html5-layered-canvases-to-one-image-in-javascript) might help

Comment: Yes it does! Thanks a lot :)